# Google Spreadsheet formatting a column to turn into multiple ones by splitting them

Tags: arrays, split, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet that has many, many rows that look like this:

Abdrashitov         Ablai        DLPNQ915    1138     4    0    OR

These are all in one cell though. I am trying to get it to be the same values in different cells.

This is what I have tried:

`=SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(Info!A1:A982), "")` (Info! is the sheet the values are in)

After this, I get the error:

```
Function SPLIT parameter 1 value should be non-empty.
```

Which does not allow me to do this. I have tried googling and looking through StackOverFlow, though I cannot find anything...

The closest thing that I was able to find was this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(" "&Info!A1:A982,
"^"&REPT("\.[^ ]*",COLUMN(OFFSET(Info!A1,,,1,4))-1)&"\.([^ ]*)")))
```

Though, it does not do anything and stays blank.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=transpose(split(join(" ",Info!A1:A)," "))
```

Comment: Hey! I think you are getting near it. However, here is the error:

Text result of JOIN is longer than the limit of 50000 characters.

Comment: How many rows do you have in your sheet? Try changing A1:A to A1:A1000 and see if that works.